# How can I validate a search box in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to do the client-side validation for a search box in AngularJs.

I tried the following,

```
<form name="search" ng-submit="myFunction()">
  <div class="input-group" ng-class="{ error: search.mysearchbox.$invalid }">                            
    <input name="mysearchbox" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search" ng-minlength="12" ng-maxlength="12" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/">
    <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search" ng-click="myFunction()" ng-style="{ 'cursor': 'pointer' }" />
  </div>
</form>
```

But not works as expected.

Can anyone post the answer?

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: can you describe what you expect and whats coming out ? it will be best if you put up a fiddle.

Comment: @prince, can renaming form/model to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think, your validation not working correct, cause your `<form name="search"` and input model `ng-model="search"` has same names.
Please rename something from this.

**UPDATE:**
Yeah, problem was in same ng-model and form names. I create jsfiddle for you and check the issue.
It's jsfiddle with correct validation:

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/2880/

Answer (score 0):

ng-model and form has the same name.

So search.mysearchbox can't find the right value.